# Type Error: 'NoneType' object is not scriptable

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I am trying to Generate the possible **permutations and combinations** of sentences from the given raw input statement using Spacy.io. At first, I generated the **Dependency Parse** tree and started traversing the tree.

Dependency Tree for the input statement: [Click here to see the Dependency Tree](https://demos.explosion.ai/displacy/?text=So%20I%20am%20not%20asking%20you%20to%20decide%20anything%20right%20now%20because%20I%20just%20called%20to%20give%20you%20some%20information%20so%20that%20anytime%20may%20be%20now%20or%20%20%20in%20the%20near%20future%20if%20you%20plan%20to%20expand%20your%20business%20or%20do%20some%20renovations%20or%20purchase%20any%20equipment%20or%20get%20another%20store%20or%20anything%20like%20that%20you%20can%20contact%20us%20at%20that%20time%20okay&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=0&cph=0)

The below is the sample code I used to traverse the tree.

```
def traverse_the_tree(doc,root,init_track,call_from):
    generated_sentence = [[],[],[]]
    subjects = list(root.lefts)
    objects = list(root.rights)
    #traverse through LeftSubTree
    for left_ST in subjects:
       generated_sentence[0].append(left_ST)
    #append the root
    generated_sentence[1].append(root)
    #traverse through RightSubTree
    for right_ST in objects:
        #check if the SubTree
        if(check_if_has_subtree(right_ST)): #return True or False
             generated_sentence[2].append(right_ST)
             #write this outerfile
             with open("output.txt","a") as fp:
                  fp.write("{},{},{}".format(generated_sentence[0],generated_sentence[1],generated_sentence[2]))    
        else:
             traverse_the_tree(doc,right_ST,init_track,call_from)
```

This is the major syntax of the code. Though my original code stills describe a lot.I post my full code here [Click here for Code](https://github.com/Madhivarman/Clause-IR-Extraction/blob/master/main.py).

When I run this code I get the following traceback error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 183, in
>
> ```
> generate_the_sentence(doc,root,init_track,call_from)   File "main.py", line 161, in generate_the_sentence
>
> generate_the_sentence(doc,right_ST,init_track,call_from)   File "main.py", line 155, in generate_the_sentence
>
> write_to_output_file(subj_rel[0],subj_rel[1],[right_ST]) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Sample output I want to Generate, from the input sentence. [Click here to see the Docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/152hl2cMDA82i9X9Ubxman2WJVSjyXsWfYa5aIBLbEG4/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks!

Comment: The traceback isn't for the code you posted. `subj_rel` isn't what you expect, so try printing it just before the line that fails. Then work back from there.

Comment: Updated the Traceback error relevant to the GitHub code. @tdelaney